# Alamofire way for "setImageWithURLRequest: placeholderImage: success:" in AFNetworking

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, alamofireimage

I'm trying to present images from url in a collection view. So far I was using AFNetworking for this, but now I'm moving to Alamofire.
I can not find a proper way to present the image like I was doing with the method 'setImageWithURLRequest: placeholderImage: success:'
Do I need to use AFNetworking in order to do this right? Is there a Alamofire way to do this that I'm skipping?
Thanks in advance

**Edit**
I'm currently using AlamofireImage
Here is the code I'm using:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString)
  .responseImage { response in        
    if let image = response.result.value {
      self.imageView.image = image
    }
}
```

My problem is that this code is inside 'cellForItemAtIndexPath' method, and every time I scroll the images are recharged again and again. This wasn't happening with AFNetworking

Comment: The image handling methods aren't in the main Alamofire repo, they are in an extra component library: https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage

Comment: Check the edit, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `UIImageView` extension in Alamofire to set the image from a URL. There is some very detailed documentation in the [README](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage#uiimageview-extension).

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
let URL = NSURL(string: "https://httpbin.org/image/png")!

imageView.af_setImageWithURL(URL)
```

Best of luck!